# How to loop list class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have below  class. And data is serialized using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. The data is returning from list. But I want to loop using for or for each. Please advice.

Thank you.

```
    var result = client.getInvocieLine
    (call Context);

   string strResultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\jsondata\invoicedata.json", strResultJson);

   string fileName = @"D:\jsondata\invoicedata.json";
   string jsonText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName)
  List<EInvoiceModel.Class1> data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EInvoiceModel.Class1>>(jsonText);

            EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline invoicelined = new EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline();

            for(int i=0; i < data.Count; i++)
            {
                invoicelined.parmItemId = data[i].invoiceLines[i].parmItemId; //Its bring only one record. I need all record from data. Please advice.
            }
            return Ok(invoicelined);
```

Please find my EInvoiceModel contains below structure, Which i designed as per my json response. yes I need same index for data and invoiceLines in data[i].invoiceLines[i]. How can I get this to return all values. Index currently pointing only one record and return one record. If I change position its return another record. But I need all please.

```
public class Class1
{
    public Invoiceline[] invoiceLines { get; set; }
    public string parmCustName { get; set; }
    public DateTime parmInvoiceDate { get; set; }       
}     public class Invoiceline
{           
    public string parmItemId { get; set; }
    public string parmItemNameDisplay { get; set; }
    public float parmQty { get; set; }}
```

Please find my json structure. I wist to repeat all parameter-ids from json response.

```
{"invoiceLines":[{"parmCurrencyCode":null,"parmCustExchRate":0.0,"parmInvoiceId":null,"parmItemId":null,"parmItemNameDisplay":null,"parmQty":0.0,"parmSalesLinePercent":0.0,"parmSalesUnit":null,"parmdiscountAmount":0.0,"parmnetTotal":0.0,"parmsalesPrice":0.0,"parmsalesTotal":0.0,"parmtotalItemsLineDisc":0.0,"parmtotalTaxableFees":0.0}],"parmCustName":null,"parmInvoiceDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","parmInvoiceId":null,"parmSalesId":null,"parmnetAmount":0.0,"parmtotalAmount":0.0,"parmtotalAmountWithDisc":0.0,"parmtotalItemsDiscountAmount":0.0,"parmtotalSalesAmount":0.0}
```

Please I want return all parmItemId below way. I don't want damage my json structure.

```
      EInvoiceModel.Class1 ds = new EInvoiceModel.Class1();
       List<EInvoiceModel.Class1> data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EInvoiceModel.Class1>>(jsonText);
       // List<EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline> data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline>>(jsonText);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {

            ds.invoiceLines = new List<EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline>
        {
             new EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline
             {
             parmItemId = data[i].invoiceLines[i].parmItemId
             }
        };
           

        }
        return Ok(ds);
```

Comment: What is your class `EInvoiceModel`

Comment: invoicelined= data[i].invoiceLines; perhaps? is a blind guess, as @PeterSmith said it depends on your class and data structure

Comment: In your loop you are *overwriting* that `invoicelined.parmItemId`. You may want to add it to a list. Also, are you sure you need the same index for data and invoiceLines in `data[i].invoiceLines[i]`?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Please find my EInvoiceModel contains below structure, Which i designed as per my json response.   public class Class1
        {
            public Invoiceline[] invoiceLines { get; set; }
            public string parmCustName { get; set; }
            public DateTime parmInvoiceDate { get; set; }       
        }     public class Invoiceline
        {
             
            public string parmItemId { get; set; }
            public string parmItemNameDisplay { get; set; }
            public float parmQty { get; set; }
       
         
        }

Comment: @Faqruddin please update your question instead of adding it as comment

Comment: @Hans Kesting. yes I need same index for data and invoiceLines in data[i].invoiceLines[i]. How can I get this to return all values. Index currently pointing only one record and return one record. If I change position its return another record. But I need all please.

Answer (score 1):

You have used to Generic list

To get all list

```
List<EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline> data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline>>(jsonText);

List<EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline> invoicelines = new List<EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline>();

for(int i=0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    invoicelines.Add(new EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline()
      {
         parmItemId = data[i].parmItemId
      });
}
return Ok(invoicelines);
```

Comment: Still its returning one value only. Its not returning all parmItemId inside that list.

Comment: Could you please share JSON file structure?

Comment: Please check I updated.

Comment: Could you please check the updated answer?

Comment: No records returned :)

Comment: Please check my updated last code. I need to refer base class(Class1) than refer base class to  public List<Invoiceline> invoiceLines { get; set; } to get all values from invoice lines.

Comment: Also please find updated json structure. Thank you

Comment: @Faqruddin the trick that Ajay is trying to explain to you is that if you want to return multiple values, you shouldn't overwrite a single value, but build a *list* (and return that). You know better what to collect and return, so adjust to your needs

Comment: @Hans I completely agree. I can return the response directly with list. Which Can bring all the data within the list. Its ok. But consider above my case the class 1 refere to InvoiceLine. InvoiceLine is list list of values. Now same class1 refer also other attributes like parmcutname and parminvoicedate. So How can I return this ? I'm considering parmcustname and parminvoicedat as header details. I dont want repeat two values with list. So thats why I need to refere class1 to refer to invoiceline and loop those values. Check my last updated code please . Thank you.

Comment: @Faqruddin in your last block of code, you keep overwriting `ds.invoiceLines` with a new list with a single entry. Try and fill that `ds.invoiceLines` with an empty list, *once*, *before* the loop. And in the loop, instead of adding a new `EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline` to a new list, `Add()` it to your existing `ds.invoiceLines`

Comment: @Hans. Could you please post your answer with code. That would be much easier to understand. Thank you.

Comment: @Hans. Could you please post your answer with code. That would be great help and easier to understand for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You now have this:

```
EInvoiceModel.Class1 ds = new EInvoiceModel.Class1();

for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    ds.invoiceLines = new List<EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline>
       {
           new EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline
           {
              parmItemId = data[i].invoiceLines[i].parmItemId
           }
        };
}
```

This means that on every iteration you *overwrite* that `ds.invoiceLines` with a new list, containing a single item. So you end up with only the last one.

A possibly better way would be this:

```
EInvoiceModel.Class1 ds = new EInvoiceModel.Class1();
ds.invoiceLines = new List<EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline>(); // create a list once

for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    // add one item to that list
    ds.invoiceLines.Add(new EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline
           {
              parmItemId = data[i].invoiceLines[i].parmItemId
           }
        );
}
```

This way you assign a new (empty) list *once* (you can skip this when invoiceLines already contains an empty list, after you created a new Class1).

And then, in the loop, you don't assign a new list, but just *add* a new item to that existing list. At the end, you get a list with as many items as there are in your input `data`.

---

By the way, this assumes that you really need to make a list of `data[i].invoiceLines[i].parmItemId`. I find it curious that for data[3] you need an invoiceLines[3] and for data[7] an invoiceLines[7]. I would expect one loop through all `data` and then an inner loop over all its `invoiceLines`. But you know *your* data best.

---

Apparently, you *do* need to loop over the inner objects. So modify that code like this:

```
EInvoiceModel.Class1 ds = new EInvoiceModel.Class1();
ds.invoiceLines = new List<EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline>(); // create a list once

// loop over all "data" items
for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    // then loop over the invoiceLines inside the current data item
    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].invoiceLines.Count(); j++)
    {
        // add one item to that list
        ds.invoiceLines.Add(new EInvoiceModel.Invoiceline
           {
              parmItemId = data[i].invoiceLines[j].parmItemId
           }
        );
    }
}
```

Note that I still use index `i` in `data[i]` from the outer loop, but now use index `j` in `invoiceLines[j]` from the inner loop.

Comment: Great Sir. I did the same. Your absolutely right. we loop data[i] but but still we need inner-loop over all its invoiceLines. Could you please add to above code inner loop over all its invoice lines. So I can repeat all lines. This will save time. Thank you.